# fetching information with scrapy(Python)

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy

when I want to capture the following information:

```
<td>But<200g/M2</td>


name = fila.select('.//td[2]/text()').extract()
```

I capture the following

```
"But"
```

apparently there is a conflict with these characters "< /"

Comment: ?From the command line, what is the output of: `scrapy version -v`

Comment: ?From within Scrapy (shell or script), what is the output of: `from scrapy.selector import XPathSelector; XPathSelector`

Answer (score 0):

escape special characters with a '\', so :

```
But\<200g\/M2
```

note that creating a file with those characters wouldn't be so easy

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that uses BeautifulSoup, in case you have more luck with a different library:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""<html><head><title>StackOverflow-Question</title></head><body>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>Ifs</td>
   <td>Ands</td>
   <td>But<200g/M2</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body></html>""")

print soup.find_all('td')[2].get_text()
```

The output of this is:

```
But<200g/M2
```

If you wanted to use XPath you could also use [The ElementTree XML API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support).  Here I'm using BeautifulSoup to take HTML and convert it to valid XML so I can run an XPath query against it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

html = """<html><head><title>StackOverflow-Question</title></head><body>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>Ifs / Ands / Or</td>
   <td>But<200g/M2</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body></html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

root = ET.fromstring(soup.prettify())

print root.findall('.//td[2]')[0].text
```

The output of this is the same (note that the HTML is slightly different, this is because XPath arrays start at one while Python arrays start at 0).